# How to test C++ code when using C functions

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, googletest

I wrote a c++ class, this class uses the c function library written by a third party.

```cpp
extern "C" {
#include "nats/nats.h"
}

class NatsConnection {
  public:
  void Connect() {
    natsConnection_Connect(&natsConnection_, natsOptions_);
    natsConnection_SubscribeSync(&natsSubscription_, natsConnection_,
                                 configuration_.subject.c_str());
    // some other c++ code.
  }
}
```

The above class uses functions imported from c: `natsConnection_Connect`, `natsConnection_SubscribeSync`.

Now I need to write a unit test to cover `some other c++ code`， I am using `gtest`, I know how to mock a C++ class, but once I use the C code I don’t know how to start.

how do i write the test? Is there has a best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are to test the C++ class, then mock that one and treat it as one unit no matter what it calls internally.

If you want to test the internals of the C++ class including C function calls, then C functions are commonly mocked by simple `#define` function-like macros. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function (int x)
{
  printf("%d\n", x);
}

#define function(x) function(1)

int main (void)
{
  function(2); // prints 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you want to write a unit test for the C functions. Maybe you can write a wrapper for the C functions, sth like:

```cpp
return_type natsConnection_Connect_CPP(arg1, arg2, ..., argN)
{
return natsConnection(arg1,arg2,...,argN);
};
```

Then you can use gtest for your function. I am unfamiliar with gtest tho, as I never used it before.